# Displaying Text Content

Tags: c#, wpf, text

Pretty simple one I hope. I have an article of text that I want to display in a window. Now rather than have this massive load of text in the centre of my code, can I add it as a Resource and read it out to the window somehow?

For those asking why, it's simply because it is a massive article and would be very ugly looking stuck in the middle of my code.

**UPDATE FOR H.B.**

I have tried a number of different approaches to this and am currently looking into the `GetManifestResourceStream` and using an embeddedResource (txt file) and writing that out to screen. Haven't finished testing it yet but if it works it would be a heck of a lot nicer than copying and pasting the entire text `txtbox1.Text = "...blah blah blah"`.

```
_textStreamReader = new    
StreamReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Problem.Explaination.txt"));
                        try
                        {
                            if (_textStreamReader.Peek() != -1)
                            {
                                txtBlock.Text = _textStreamReader.ReadLine();
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Error writing text!");
                        }
```

My query remains, is there a better way of achieving this (assuming this is even successful)
Thanks

**NOTE**

In my example above I only want one line of text. If you were adapting this to read a number of lines from a file you would change it like so;

```
StreamReader _textStreamReader;
        _textStreamReader = new StreamReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Problem.Explaination.txt"));
        var fileContents = _textStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        _textStreamReader.Close();

        String[] lines = fileContents.Split("\n"[0]);
        String[] lines2;
        Int16 count;
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
        txtBlock.Text += line;
        }
```

Comment: Is this article static text? It's not common to place such stuff within resources. I'm not even talking about code.

Comment: To answer the question - yes, of course you can, and I'm sure you'll get a more proper answer within minutes that'll help you figure out how. But to reiterate AnatoliiG's comment - why? To better be able to understand and help you, it'd be good to know the reason. =)

Comment: @downvoter Reason for down vote?

Comment: @killianmcc: Read the down-arrow's tooltip...

Comment: @killianmcc: Usually you should also list those approaches and explain the problems with them...

Comment: @H.B. I can't remember the other approaches it's been that long working on this, so I guess this answer will have to do. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the file as a resource and, in your code, load it into a string.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (var stream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.TextFile.txt"))
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(line);
        }
    }
    ViewModel.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could place that text in a text file, and read it out in code

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx

Comment: Yes that's what I'm messing around with at the moment but I need the text file copied with the exe so I'm trying to use `ManifestResourceStream`.